# DYLD: Lazy Symbol

Tags: macos, dyld, scanning

What seems to be the cause of this error after performing scanimage on Mac terminal:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FUNCTIONName

Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/sane/libsane-xxxxx.1.so

Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FUNCTIONName

Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/sane/libsane-xxxxx.1.so

Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if dyld can't find a symbol then you could have one of several problems.

1. dyld can't find the library because it isn't there.
2. dyld can't find the library because it's linker path was wrong.
3. dyld can't find the symbol in the library because it isn't in the library for some reason.

Once you find the library, you should be able to use `nm library | grep symbol` to figure out if the symbol is in the library.

you didn't mention if you were seeing this on your build machine or on a different machine, which would be a clue, good luck.

Comment: Hello! My library is in /usr/lib/ but it's .so since I am trying to let my program in linux ubuntu work in mac osx as well. Do I need to convert my libxxx.so to libxxx.dylib? Are .so libraries accepted in mac osx?

Comment: yeah you will have to rebuild / or reinstall

Comment: @newbieMACuser if you plan on distributing the software then you will have to go through more steps in order to make it work (it has to be bundled in the .app and has to have the correct DYLD path set... probably with (at)rpath it is kind of complicated, so if you don't have a working example, try to find a tutorial.)